# Firebase Crash Library - NullPointerException in the console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I've implemented the new Firebase Crash library (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/crash) to log error in Android app.

Anyone is having similar problem.

I'm checking errors and on the top I've got:

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference
android.util.Base64.decode (Base64.java:118)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeH (zzg.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeE (zzg.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzCd (zzd.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzc (zzd.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.getToken (zzd.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken (FirebaseInstanceId.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzUo (FirebaseInstanceId.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza (FirebaseInstanceIdService.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm (FirebaseInstanceIdService.java:)
com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run (zzb.java:)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

I have checked but there are not extra proguard rules for Firebase Crash. 
Is it bug in the library? Anyone is having similar problem?

I can't reproduce error on my devices.

The error is strange and I don't know in which place in the application. Nothing so I think it's connected to Crash library.

This is not standard nullexception. It's connected to Firebase Crash library. Why I'm thinking this is library bug - there is no sign on my code/activity here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Jens how this is duplicate? This is connected to Firebase Crash library. I know what is NullException but in the example it's the problem with the library and I want to know if this is a bug in library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was confirmed by Google that this was bug in the InstanceID library.

All you can do right now is to update to the latest version and hope this will be fixed.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
```

**Note #1**

**You can see in the comments that some people are still getting this error.** At the moment we can't do nothing more than update to the latest version. If you've been using previous version - update to the latest. We need info from Firebase team about it.

**Note #2**
This seems to be fixed in 9.4.0 but we still need confirmation

Comment: The bug is not fixed. I'm still getting the error when using the latest (9.2.0) version.

Comment: @adek Your answer is not clear, you say that it's not fixed but at the same time to update to 9.2.0? Does this version fix it?

Comment: @adek Thanks for the update! I have still a question tough, in my app I only have for now `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'`, what is the use of this "firebase-crash" plugin? It is necessary to fix the bug or do I just update "firebase-ads" to 9.2.0?

Comment: @YoannHercouet if you don't use crash library no need to worry about. firebase-crash is Crash - bug console - similar product to Crashlytics (but from google). If you don't use it you shoudn't see this bug.

Comment: @adek The thing is, I am also getting those errors, I am so tired of getting bugs from Google they never plan to fix...

Comment: @ian-barber do you have more info about this bug?

Comment: I don't use firebase-crash but still get the bug. I guess the lib is pulled from other play-services libs like gcm or analytics

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be fixed in

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
```

Comment: This saved me a lot of time... Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in the InstanceID library in 9.0, sorry. We've identified a fix and will include it in a future SDK release.

We believe it should be fairly rare, but please comment if you're seeing a large number of devices.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this, this exact same stack. I've just added firebase core and ads. Can you tell us around when will it be fixed?

Comment: Issue found on sm_g7102 and sm_j700h

Comment: Device Crashes 
Samsung Galaxy A3(2016) 3.0
Unidentified 3.0
LGE V10 2.0
Motorola Moto G3 2.0
LG G Stylo 2.0
Samsung Galaxy Note3(T-Mobile) SM-N900T 1.0
Google Nexus 5 1.0
HTC One 1.0
Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 1.0
Huawei PLK-UL00 1.0
HTC HTC ONE A9 1.0
Huawei Honor 5X 1.0
Samsung Galaxy J3 1.0
Samsung GALAXY J5 SM-J500H 1.0
Huawei P8 Lite 1.0
Motorola Moto E2 1.0
HTC Desire 626s 1.0
Samsung Galaxy A5 Duos 1.0
Samsung Galaxy A5 1.0
Motorola Quark / Droid Turbo 1.0
LG G3 Beat 1.0
Samsung Galaxy S6 1.0

Comment: @Ian Barber, do you have any news about this? I'm getting more than 20 crashes a day. It is now the number one issue of my app.

Comment: GT-I9060I, SM-G920F, SM-G7102, SM-N915F, SM-N9005, D6503, SM-G925F, HUAWEI Y625-U32, ALE-L21, GT-N7100, SM-N9005, SM-A500H
SM-N900, SM-J700H

Comment: LG G3 Dual. Fix now please

Comment: 50 crashes a day on this.

Comment: I am also seeing 40-50 crashes a day on this.

Comment: I'm seeing the issue with v9.2.1 using firebase core and remote config

Comment: @Ian-Barber: I'm also seeing quite a lot of these crashes in the wild (versio 9.2.1). Do you have a issue-tracker where we can follow progress on this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the comments all. We should have a full fix for this in the next version of the SDK - thanks for the reports about continuation of the issue with 9.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of Google Play Services available: 9.2.1. Apparently it has the fix inside. I'll confirm it once I have enough data.