# Google Play Services GCM 9.2.0 asks to "update" back to 9.0.0

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

So this morning I started updating to the latest version of my project libraries.

I'm trying to update GCM to the latest version 9.2.0, but I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

This is how I have my code:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
}
```

And then:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0"

    ...
}
```

Anyone having the same issue/fixed the same issue?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Apparently you have to apply your GSM plugin at the bottom of your app/build.gradle file. Else, version 9.2.0 will cause conflict in your project.

For reference, this is how my app/build.gradle file looks like now:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.neenbedankt.android-apt"

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...

    // Google Cloud Messaging
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0"

    ...
}

apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Comment: same issue here, I rolled back to 9.0.0

Comment: @mbonnin I ended up doing the same. But would surely like to know what's going on here. Haven't been lucky finding an answer yet.

Comment: And then 9.0.0 has this bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361651/firebase-crash-library-nullpointerexception-in-the-console and the solution seems to be to update to 9.2.0.... Which is not possible thanks to the bug here :-(

Comment: it's working if I apply the plugin at the end of the build.gradle file like Gusthema says bellow

Comment: Read how to correct this issue the right way in my post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41430554/3997720).

Comment: It does not make too much sense... but it works by writing that "apply plugin" at the end of the build.gradle 

Answer (score 507, accepted):

Do you have the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

line at the bottom of your app's build.gradle file?

I saw some errors when it was on the top and as it's written [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk), it should be at the bottom.

Comment: This is not the issue. And according to the official documentation, all plugins should be applied at the top. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: That's not true, gms plugin should be in the bottom of the file as you can see here on the docs for gms: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: I stand corrected. Regardless, this will not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why the first time I tried it, it did not work. Just tried it again because of @mbonnin 's comment, and it's working now. Thank you.

Comment: I had added this line in the beginning of the file, but it worked after putting it at the bottom.

Comment: I get the following after adding the line:  * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Comment: Adding the plugin at the bottom resolved the version conflict.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. I wonder why we need to put this line of code at the bottom ?

Comment: That's bizarre. Any possible explanations?

Comment: Crazy stuff!!! As you said I just moved the 'apply plugin' 'from top to bottom and it worked...

Comment: This line is important ::  :) line at the bottom of your build.gradle file?

Comment: This is upsurd... But it worked :D :D This should be reported to Google

Comment: That's  true, "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'" plugin should be in the bottom of the file, it works for me,

Answer (score 54):

**Just put this line at the bottom of your app-module's (not project root's) `gradle` file.**

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Then rebuild your project.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, today 2016 - october - 06 
I solved with this:

I changed all dependencies that began with 9.?.? to 9.6.1
I compiled with sdk version 24 and target version 17.

There is another packages in my solution because I used more things then only authentication.

After changed your build.gradle (Module:app) with the code below do it:

1. Put your package NAME in the line with the words applicationId "com.YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE"
2. Synchronize your project (Ctrl+alt+v) and Build Again.

This is the code of the file buid.gradle (Module:app) that worked for me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.YOUR_PACKAGE_HERE"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 6):

The same situation was with the previous versions. It's annoing that new versions com.google.android.gms libraries are always releasing before plugin, and it's impossible to use new version because is incompatible with old plugin. I don't know if plugin is now required (google docs sucks). I remember times when it wasn't. The only way is wait for new plugin version, or you can try to remove plugin dependencies, but as I said I'am not sure if gcm will work without it. What I know the main feature of 9.2.0 version is new Awareness API https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/google-awareness-api-in-action/en, if you didn't need it, you can use 9.0.0 version without any trouble.

Comment: Ah, go figure. Since there is no documentation stating otherwise, I assumed newest versions would roll out with the required plugin. AFAIK, you do need the plugin to make GCM work, so I'm guessing this is a manual-check-for-update solution.

Comment: For sure @yaneq google docs sucks, got the same problem right now

Answer (score 5):

Gustavomcls's solution to change com.google.* version to same version worked for me .

I change both dependancies to 9.2.1 in buid.gradle (Module:app)

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
```

Comment: I had this problem also because of firebase, but I don't like this solution to downgrade firebase version to 9.2.1

Answer (score 2):

open `app/build.gradle` from your app-module and rewrite below line after dependencies block. This allows the plugin to determine what version of Play services you are using

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I got this idea from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin). In this tutorial second point is saying that above plugin line be at the bottom of your `app/build.gradle` file so that no dependency collisions are introduced. Hope it will help you out.

Comment: Why do you repeat answers that have been given a half year ago?

Answer (score 2):

> ## For Cordova OR Ionic Hybrid App

I have the very similar problem with my Ionic 1 Cordova Build after Integrating the Firebase Cloud Messaging ( FCM )

I fixed this issue by the following steps

So one fix will be: inside **platforms/android** open **project.properties** (Its a file ) , you will have something like this

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+
```

Replace the

> +

Sign with your target version number - like the following

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0
```

Save the file

Then take build using

> ```
>  ionic cordova run android
> ```

I hope this will work for everyone

Comment: This just changed the error. That is kind of good as I have been only receiving the same error even with thousands of solutions tried.

Answer (score 2):

Add this line at the bottom of the gradle.

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

because it the top it does not work.I was facing similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you have Firebase included also, make them of same version as the error says.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have an issue with this until I tried to use the Location Services, at which point I had to put the `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of the file, rather than the top. The reason being that when you have it at the top there are collision issues, and by placing it at the bottom, you avoid those issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your target `SDK` might be higher than `SDK` of the device, change that.
For example, your device is running API 23 but your target `SDK` is 25.
Change 25 to 23.