# Google Play Services GCM 10.0.1 asks to “update” back to 9.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services, build.gradle

I'm trying to build my new project, but I get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

```xml
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.julia.android.example_project"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'API_KEY', myKey
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    wearApp project(':wear')
}
```

And

```xml
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to move `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom of my app/build.gradle file, but it didn't work out.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: check your sdk if there is any updates available for google play services.

Comment: please change your dependency all `'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'` and add plugin to bottom and sync again, if it's work then as @Chirayu said you need to update your sdk

Comment: I have Google Play services plugin Version 38 installed, I don't see how I can update it...

Comment: @JuliaKo yes your play service is upto date. now make sure to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the bottom in your gradle. and also check google repository update.

Answer (score 25):

Had this issue earlier today. Just apply the google services plugin before you apply the android application plugin.

Update the following lines:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: it works, but don't know why I can't find any explanation on google doc. it really sucks ..... btw, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I solved it looking for all the "build.grade" files in the project to change all the versions from 9.8.0 to 10.0.1 (you can do a search "find in path" to search the 9.8.0 string), I had one missing and this caused the error.

And also the line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
```

must be replaced by:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.0.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

To fix this you have to do the following.

First, even if the documentation says  "Add this"

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
 }
```

Don't do it, because that is the whole google play services API, since version 6.5 if I remember correctly google play services is a selective API, it means that you must include only what you need.

Read [this page entirely](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) until you read *Selectively compiling APIs into your executable*.

Second, check that all your version numbers are the same, you can't mix them; check the link before, and choose only what you need.

By the way the class path is

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

Not beta-1 as @JuliaKo said.

P.S. If you speak Spanish, read my post about this [here](http://android.pedro-varela.com/2016/01/cambios-en-google-play-services.html)

Comment: Latest class path is  'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

Answer (score 2):

In my case, check that not only `google-play-services`, but `firebase services` are of the same version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line after `dependencies` closure at the bottom:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem replacing this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`  to this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'`

Comment: @Fran, Yes, I did.

Comment: This is no the solution to that problem. Read my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to my own experience, you have to set that version to all the gms google services plugins. 
So, in your case you should replace

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'`
for

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
```

Besides, as other users have suggested, you have to add

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

at the bottom of the app.module graddle file