# version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin | Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, gradle-plugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
  >   [image]

Comment: Please refer this link https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy/issues/21

Comment: try to replace `compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"`
to
`compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0"`

Comment: any solution you found?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

**Easy solution** is to install this updated plugin from my github account:
Remove  fcm plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated
```

And install this updated version:

```
ionic cordova plugin add https://github.com/ishan123456789/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated.git
```

**If the above doesn't workout for you. The hard way**

A solution for the above problem as seen in some channels is to:
Go to the `plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm` or `plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependency-updated` then go to `src/android/FCMPlugin.gradle`

And replace:

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.+'
```

With

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

And core to:

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    }
```

And plugin.xml

```
    <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0" />
    <framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0" />
```

The replace took place as per the google service higher version. In my case the conflict was with google plus plugin so I went to `plugins/cordova-plugin-googleplus` and there the google service version was

```
    <preference name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" default="11.8.0"/>
    <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" />
    <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" />
```

So from here the version `11.8.0` came.

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/283

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/231

[Google Play Services GCM 10.0.1 asks to “update” back to 9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010208/google-play-services-gcm-10-0-1-asks-to-update-back-to-9-0-0)

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/499

https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm/issues/306

**This answer was quite resourceful**

[com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)