# The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,

Tags: android, build, compiler-errors

The library `com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base` is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,15.0.0], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

build error android
every time I build this I got same problem for project
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)

Answer (score 4):

For those who still have this problem on the Ionic framework. After 2 day's of trying, I succeeded to build my project.

1. `npm i cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release`
2. `npm i cordova-android-support-gradle-release`
3. In package.json under plugins, you should have this:

```
      "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release": {
        "PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "+"
      },
      "cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release": {
        "FIREBASE_VERSION": "+"
      }
```

4. In config.xml, you should have these:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.0">
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release" spec="^2.0.0">
        <variable name="FIREBASE_VERSION" value="+" />
    </plugin>
```

That's it. Hope it helps :)

Comment: sir i have tried but i got 6: error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService ?

Answer (score -1):

Remove `com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1` from Gradle and use only individual which you have required.

check [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

> Note: Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens
>   of libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the
>   specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.