# Facing error during Ionic Cordova Build Android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic3

I am facing below error during : Ionic Cordova Build Android

Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "glob" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.

and also this error in detail : https://prnt.sc/pnk076

1.Followed this solution [The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.0,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682721/the-library-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-reque) but resulted to : https://prnt.sc/pnif6x .

2.Followed this solution [Problem with play-services-measurement-base on ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56014935/problem-with-play-services-measurement-base-on-ionic) but resulted to https://prnt.sc/pniq6m

3.Followed this solution https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/android-build-falid-the-library-com-google-android-gms-play-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-various-other-libraries/163390/12 and it resulted to : https://prnt.sc/pnj11b .

4.Followed this solution [Cordova error: Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304065/cordova-error-using-requirecordovamodule-to-load-non-cordova-module-q-is-no) and it resulted to : https://prnt.sc/pnk076

5. Followed this solution [How to adjust the version of "play-services-measurement-base" with "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794688/how-to-adjust-the-version-of-play-services-measurement-base-with-cordova-andr) and resulted to : https://prnt.sc/pnkt7u

I am expecting Android Build APK without any errors.

Comment: Can you put up logs as some of the logs are not completely visible in the image?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you implement one version but other plugins reguire a different version of the com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base

You can try doing a npm ls to see which dependencies your plugins have.