# Error in building gradle - com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, firebaseui, facebook-authentication

I am trying to integrate Facebook sign in feature to my android app using Firebase-UI library. I am following this tutorial - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui?authuser=0

But I am getting below error while trying to build gradle:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Below is my app level `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "company.com.mygame"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.0'

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I saw below links -

[com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/37

But then I get this error -

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.2.0] C:\Users\me\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\firebase-ui-auth-4.2.0.aar\xxx\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 15
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 15,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.firebase.ui.auth" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

But the issue is still not fixed. I have just started learning android, not sure what am I missing.

Comment: How did you solve the first error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue

Just make sure that you have the latest versions of all the dependencies. I used the current versions for Firebase core and auth.

You can get the latest versions from [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) . 
Using the latest version at current point of time:

in app/build.gradle :

```
 dependencies {
    ...
    // Add these code
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
 }
```

in android/build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        minSdkVersion = 16
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error says : `uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 15 cannot be smaller than version 16` and your `build.gradle` as `minSdkVersion 15`. Try to change it to `16`  and see if that works for you.

All the best for learning android. May the force be with you.

Over and out,

Aashish