# Firebase + Google Play Services = Error: "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement ... [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1"

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I was getting my own version of the following error using vanilla Android (no React voodoo), and the other hacky solutions, namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50922399/1923016), didn't work for me, so I'm posting what did.

After implementing firebase-core

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'`

in my Android project that was currently using

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

for Google Play location services, I got the following error:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1

Answer (score -1):

I just changed the lines in my app/build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

and did a **Build** > **Clean Project**