# Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfg

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle

I tried find solution on internet but nothink work for me. 
After implement firebase analytics my program display this error. 
Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfg

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
   dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.6';
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.2'
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
}
```

Comment: remove `com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true` and then fix the actual issue. just before removed an answer from yesterday, which had been completely ignored, despite it solved the version conflicts... with just the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the dependencies to the latest version for

com.google.android.gms:play-services and com.google.firebase:

Looks like it was discussed here:

[com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)