# com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]]

Tags: android, android-studio

The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew:app:dependencies.

This error always appears whenever i add the below plugin to my project which is connected to firebase. apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Did you try the suggestion "Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew:app:dependencies" to find out what is pulling in the library?

Comment: @Pankaj-Yadav What libraries are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true`
put it on the bottom of build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your google-play services library to this in your build.gradle at the project level:

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

And if using for firebase-auth add the library in the build.gradle at the app level:

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'