# When I connect Firebase with my Android Gradle I have this problem

Tags: android

The ERROR:

> The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being
>   requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but
>   resolves to 16.1.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies
>   tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

How do I solved this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)

Comment: Paste your build.gradle file show that we can help you

Comment: Make sure you the latest versions of the play-services and firebase dependencies

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all play services and firebase libraries latest version to your project which are required. You can see this link which will be helpful for you.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Comment: every thing is new but can't

Comment: use different versions for every dependency firebase-messaging, firebase-core etc. they are different version for every dependency now. you can not use only one dependency now. You need to use different version number and please download latest updated version from sdk manager. And if you are using third party library then please check their dependencies.