# I got error when add AdMob ads in my project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have implemented in `Firebase` in my android studio project and it's working fine but when i added `AdMob` code according to these instructions in it I am getting this error.

[Instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start/)

`ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.3.0,16.3.0], [16.0.0,16.0.0]], but resolves to 16.3.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies`.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe this topic may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your project gradle, use this version of firebase-core.  This should solve the issue!

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'﻿
```

Comment: complete code                         // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}