# Running react-native run-android gives error with com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid

Tags: react-native

Trying to run react-native run-android but this gives me error. The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid is being requested by various other libraries at [[16.0.1,16.0.1], [17.0.0,17.0.0]], but resolves to 17.0.0. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies

Answer (score 0):

// build.graddle :

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Gradle-Plugin/issues/37

[com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base is being requested by various other libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577437/com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement-base-is-being-requested-by-vari)