# Google auth error at gradle syncing

Tags: android, synchronization, google-play-services

I wanted to sync gradle while using Google auth, so I have its newest version at the dependencies section:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
```

But I got this error instead:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

UPDATE: The fix was here: [Google Play Services GCM 9.2.0 asks to "update" back to 9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127053/google-play-services-gcm-9-2-0-asks-to-update-back-to-9-0-0)

Comment: possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127053/google-play-services-gcm-9-2-0-asks-to-update-back-to-9-0-0

Comment: you're right, It's working now